# What's the "caHide, caNone" Database Equivalent?

Tags: database, delphi

When I want to confirm a form exit, I use a `DialogMsg` call with an if to set `Action` parameter to `caNone` (No) or `caHide` (yes).

When I use that approach with database table row posting, I get a problem.

If I make a Save button with a confirmation dialog, I could call `Post` or `Cancel`, but when I have a Database `Grid` in the form, the problem comes when the user alter a row and later, selects another row, witch saves the previous row automatically.

The solution I found was to put the save confirmation dialog inside the `OnBeforePost`, but if the uses says No, how should I cancel the `Post` command to Continue? I've tryed `Cancel` and `Abort` commands, but it continues saving the row.

Comment: IMHO the `Abort` called from the `OnBeforePost` event should prevent from a data post. Could you show your code sample ?

Comment: I use a `MessageDlg` with an `IF` that when the user says No, I executes a `Cancel` and the an `Abort`. This returns the row to it's preview state, but prevents the table to go to the row the user selected on the grid.

Comment: Once you Abort, the UI wouldn't navigate to the user clicked row, of course, because you're aborting that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own descendant `TMyQuery` of the `TXxxQuery` (or what else dataset kind you are using). And in your class override `Post` method and add a new event, allowing to decide is the `Post` needed. Then register new component and replace `TXxxQuery` in your application with `TMyQuery`. And create the event handler.

For example, the `TMyQuery`:

```
interface

type
  TMyAllowPostEvent = procedure (ASender: TDataSet; var AAllow: Boolean) of object;
  TMyQuery = class (TXxxQuery)
  private
    FOnAllowPost: TMyAllowPostEvent;
  public
    procedure Post; override;
  published
    property OnAllowPost: TMyAllowPostEvent read FOnAllowPost write FOnAllowPost;
  end;

implementation

procedure TMyQuery.Post;
var
  lAllow: Boolean;
begin
  lAllow := True;
  if Assigned(OnAllowPost) then
    OnAllowPost(Self, lAllow);
  if lAllow then
    inherited Post;
end;
```

And the example of the event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.MyQuery1AllowPost(ASender: TDataSet; var AAllow: Boolean);
begin
  AAllow := MessageDlg('Would you like to save changes ?', mtConfirmation, mbYesNo, -1) = mrYes;
end;
```